# While in an audit, you can't add a comment

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

Just got to decide if an answer should be deleted. It was only a link, no comments. So I wanted to add a comment explaining why link only answers aren't welcome, and got "This is an audit". This defeats the whole audit process, I could randomly try to add a comment to see if I'm being audited.

Is it that hard just to accept the comment, maybe even allow to edit it, and discard it afterwards? The machinery to do so is surely extant.

Comment: The audit process is a bit of a ... paperclip optimisation for people who try to simply click looks ok or such through the whole queue. If you try to comment, the goal of the review audit, to check if you are paying attention is met

Comment: Then make the "This is an audit only" the end of the process...